# Imagemagick - Same command gives different output in PHP or console

Tags: php, image, imagemagick, ubuntu-12.04

I'm trying to use ImageMagick on an Ubuntu 12.04 server to create simple business cards dynamically. This is done via a php page. I tried to install MagickWand, but it didn't really work so I'm now using ImageMagick syntax and executing it via PHP function `exec()`.

I'm making good progress, and had the basics more or less done, the output image looked okay and am now finetuning, setting the positions right, changing fonts and sizes, etc.

Our graphic person wants the text to be in Arial with bold titles, so I installed msttcorefonts on the server. Since then, the text in the output image is italic, and it ignores whatever font I use.

The curious thing is: if I echo the command to the page, copy and paste it into the ubuntu console, the image that's created there uses the right fonts and is exactly what I want.

So, it seems that when I execute the command via console, everything is fine, but when I execute it in PHP via `exec()`, ImageMagick doesn't seem to recognize the fonts. Does anyone know why? Also, if it doesn't recognize the font, why does it default to italic, or, for that matter, why did the default change at all after installing the fonts?

This is the command I'm currently testing (with changed names and contact info):

```
 convert                                                     \
    -size 1051x697                                           \
     xc:none                                                 \
    -density 300                                             \
    -fill white                                              \
     draw "rectangle 0,0 1051,697"                           \
    -fill black                                              \
    -font Arial-Negreta                                      \
    -pointsize 9                                             \
    -draw "text 140,175 'Hotel Example'"                     \
    -font Arial-Normal                                       \
    -pointsize 6                                             \
    -draw "text 140,220 'Example Street 8'"                  \
    -draw "text 140,240 '12345 Exampletown'"                 \
    -draw "text 140,280 'Telefon: 123 45 67 89 0'"           \
    -draw "text 140,300 'Fax: 234 56 78 90'"                 \
    -draw "text 140,340 'http://www.example.de'"             \
    -draw "text 140,360 'hotel-example@example.de'"          \
    -stroke none -fill orange -draw "rectangle 1,32 1050,75" \
    -fill grey                                               \
    -draw "rectangle 1,75 1050,100"                          \
    -fill orange                                             \
    -draw "rectangle 1,626 1050,665"                         \
     test_front.png
```

Edit:

I just noticed that running the command from the Ubunut console also only works in my home directory, and not in my /var/www directory. As APiK pointed out, it's probably a user thing.

Comment: I wanted to upvote it. The thing is, I've only just registered, and when I try to upvote, I only get a message telling me that I need at least 15 reputation for that.

Comment: Ah... I wasn't aware you'd need 15 reputation points in order to be allowed to upvote...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you installed the fonts only for a specific user.
Try to run this command in console and PHP script:

```
# This will show you all the available fonts for ImageMagick
$ convert -list type
```

Or you can also specify TTF fonts directly:

```
$ convert -font /path/to/your/fonts.ttf
```

Comment: Ah, that would also explain the edit why it only works when I'm in my home directory, as I just noticed (see Edit). I'm woefully new linux as well as ImageMagick, so I'm kind of fighting on two fronts here :) Thanks for the tip, I'll try using the complete path for now.
Is there a way to make the fonts available for all users, or do I have to reinstall them?

Comment: If you've installed the font using `$ sudo apt-get install msttcorefonts` then it should work.

You can try to run: `$ sudo fc-cache -fv` to regenerate the fonts cache. What is the output of PHP `exec('convert -list type')` ?

Comment: Yeah, I used the apt-get. I had to use ´convert -list font´ as a command. I tried that both in PHP and in my command line and compared the results. Then I saw that the font could be found in both, but for some reason under a different name. In the Ubuntu output, it was called "Arial-Fett" and "Arial-Standard", while in the PHP output the correct names are "Arial-Negreta" and "Arial-Normal". I'm not sure where the name difference comes from, but when I use the proper name, it works. Thanks for nudging me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

I doubt your font names `Arial-Fett` and `Arial-Standard` are recognized by ImageMagick.

To see which names for Arial font faces are known to `convert`, run this command first:

```
convert -list font | grep -i arial
```

On my system (a Mac OS Lion), I get this result:

```
  [....]
  Font: Arial-Narrow-Negreta-cursiva
    family: Arial Narrow
    glyphs: /Library/Fonts/Arial Narrow Bold Italic.ttf
  Font: Arial-Narrow-Normal
    family: Arial Narrow
    glyphs: /Library/Fonts/Arial Narrow.ttf
  Font: Arial-Negreta
    family: Arial
    glyphs: /Library/Fonts/Arial Bold.ttf
  Font: Arial-Negreta-cursiva
    family: Arial
    glyphs: /Library/Fonts/Arial Bold Italic.ttf
  Font: Arial-Normal
    family: Arial
    glyphs: /Library/Fonts/Arial.ttf
  [....]
```

With ImageMagick, you can only apply these two methods to specify the font to use:

- ...either use *exactly* the names that appear after the `Font:` tag,
- ...or use *exactly* the path+name to the specific font file that appears after the `glyphs:` tag (if filename or path use spaces, enclose it in quotes!).

So on my system, for your `-font Arial-Standard` I'd have to use either of

```
-font Arial-Normal
-font /Library/Fonts/Arial.ttf
```

Instead of your `-font Arial-Fett` I'd have to use either of

```
-font Arial-Negreta
-font "/Library/Fonts/Arial Bold.ttf"
```

On your system this may be different of course (esp. if you're on Windows or Linux). That's why you have to verify using `convert -list font`...

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem. I tried `identify -list font` at first and in that list it did indeed say "Arial-Fett", that's why I was confused that ImageMagick didn't recognize it. So, does `convert` "translate" the localized name to the standard one? Or for that matter, why are there even different names on the system? I'd have thought I'd either have a localised name or a standard English one, not both.

Comment: @Christian: I'm really surprised by your finding. I think I'll ask in the ImageMagick forum about it.  (If you really see "Arial-Fett" in your environment, then I'd expect this name to also work.)

Comment: I only find it when using it in my home directory, apparently. Anywhere else, all bets are off, which is why it won't work when used from PHP. It seems to be some kind of user-dependant thing. But it works now, and apparently this is the "proper" way, so I won't research this further for now - too much else to do :)

Edit: I can't get used to the fact that I can't insert a line break by pressing enter when writing a comment :)